# Exercise 12.10 from the book Scheme and the art of programming

Tags: scheme, lisp

The exercise 12.10, in the chapter about object oriented programming
We build a queue data structure by make a function `queue-maker`.
In this function, we handle the messages that send to the object
for example, when we send the object the message `enqueue!` and the operand "a" => "a" will be push to the queue

```
(define q (queue-maker))
(q 'enqueue! 'a)
```

What is need to do is add handler for the message `enqueue-list!` with the operand will be a list. That will add all the items in the list to the queue

```
(q 'enqueue-list! '(b c d))
```

The question here is why we don't use the `append!` function to modify the queue?

Comment: What does the handler use? `append`? Or is writing the handler an exercise?

Comment: Oh, I see the book explain it but I was not reading it. I think I should read it now. You can download the book and read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `append!` is a disaster for *either* implementation of queues given in the book.

Exercise 12.10 asks you to use the version defined in Program 12.15.  This is the version that uses a tail pointer to make `enqueue!` efficient.  There are two ways you could use `append!` in this implementation:

1. You could `append!` to the queue list directly.  This (a) does not make use of the tail pointer and thus has to walk the whole queue and, worse, (b) does not *update* the tail-pointer, trashing the data structure, so that the next time you call `enqueue!` you will lose everything you have just added.  You could repair this by then updating the tail pointer to point at the new last cons which negates any supposed performance advantage of using `append!`.  But this is *not safe anyway*, see below.
2. You could `append!` to the tail pointer which points at the last cons of the queue.  This is better, but you still must remember to update the tail pointer to point to the new last cons, so you *still* must walk the list you are appending.  However this is *still not safe*, see below.

Approach (1) both negates the advantage of using the tail pointer and is painful to implement.  Approach (2) looks a bit better.  But, again, see below, *neither* are safe.

If you use the earlier implementation of queues, the one in program 12.13, it looks like using `append!` would work: there's no tail pointer to worry about now.  But this *also* is unsafe.

Here's why all these approaches are unsafe.

Consider this code:

```
(define (enqueue-list-twice q l)
  (q 'enqueue-list! l)
  (q 'enqueue-list! l) ;or just enqueue! anything
  l)
```

What happens if you use `append!` to implement `enqueue!`?  Well, the first time you do this you end up with a queue whose tail *is `l`*.  It's not a copy of `l`, it *is* `l`.  The second time you do this then `append!` will smash the last cons of this list, *and hence the last cons of `l`*, to be ... `l`.

So this approach has set a nasty trap for you: it's stashed away one of its arguments as part of the queue, *which will then be destructively modified*.  That's nasty.

You can fix even this by making an explicit copy of the list, which, again, negates the advantage of using `append!` since you have to walk it to copy it anyway.  By the time you've done all this it really is better just to implement the thing without having to second-guess `append!` all the way through.  The obvious, safe, approach is just to implement `enqueue-list!` by repeatedly calling `enqueue!`.

Comment: thank you @ignis, very clear and detail explanation!
Though I think in ````enqueue-list-twice ````, the second call to enqueue-list will not override the last cons cells to be ````l```` again because in the ````append!```` it will find the correct last cons cell to append ````l```` to it

Comment: I don't see the problem of `enqueue-list!` using `append!`, since `enqueue-list!` isnt' `enqueue-list`.  We document that `enqueue-list!` potentially steals the structure of the input list and destroys it, whereas `enqueue-list` uses fresh structure. So the former has to be used with great care, and that's it.

Comment: @Kaz Sorry, I missed typing ````enqueue-list````, is should be ````enqueue-list!````. We only have ````enqueue-list!````. The problem with using ````append!```` is performance, suppose your queue have 1 bilions items, the append must walk from the beginning of the list to the end of it to find the last item. We solve this by make use of another variable ````real```` that point to the last item

Comment: @WestMountain: you should try the `append!` variant (in the simple queue).  Because it does in fact do what I said it does.

Comment: @Kaz `enqueue!` mutates *the queue* not some other argument: there *is* no `enqueue` operation which, if it existed, would presumably functionally update the queue.   So should `enqueue-list!`.  However of course, yes, you can excuse terrible design with documentation.  I prefer to write programs which are not terrible however.

Comment: That's like saying `append!` is terrible design, excused by documentation. Note that mutating the queue leaves room for terrible design. If the application is allowed to retrieve the queue by just obtaining a pointer to the shared data, and if `enqueue-list` mutates that queue, then the application's snapshot will appear to mutate. The best behaved or least "terrible" `enqueue-list` always freshly allocates a queue and updates nothing more than the one slot necessary to plant the new queue in place of the old.

Comment: @Kaz: the book says 'Do not use `append!`.  Why?' (p401).  I think that makes the intention as clear as it could possibly be: you are *not meant to use `append!` to implement `enqueue-list!`* and more generally you are *not meant to mutate the second argument*.  I really don't see that it could be clearer than that.  And, once, again, there *is no* `enqueue-list`: that was a typo in the question (I have edited it now).